# Change view images/css background images based on locale with Express

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

With Express, I need to support a bunch of different languages: English, French, etc. Some of the images that are in my view need to be in the right language (some have text on the images).

How can I change the static directory based on the locale?

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // basically, this header is getting set somewhere else
    var locale = req.get('x-language-locale');
    res.locals.locale = locale || 'en-US';
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

Right now I'm passing the `locale` to the view. So in my index.jade file, I can output `#{locale}` and it will return "en-US" for example. So I technically could just include the `#{locale}` variable into the path like this

```
img(src='/dist/images/#{locale}/my-image.jpg')
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way to serve up the static directory based on the header from the start. I also need to be able to change background-images in my CSS.